# powershell raspbian execute Invoke-RestMethod from ps1

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, raspbian, powershell-core

I am working on a powershell script to connect to an api via Invoke-RestMethod.
The call to the api is public, without authenticating.
It works from within powershell but fails to execute it in a ps1 script.
My operating system is raspian with powershell core 6.1.3

Testing inside powershell work as expected:

```sh
pi@raspberry:~/Documents $ pwsh
PowerShell 6.1.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/pi/Documents> $salida = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time' -Method Get

PS /home/pi/Documents> Write-Host "Time: " $salida

Time:  @{serverTime=1569106660940}

PS /home/pi/Documents>
```

But with this ps1 script (The script has execution permissions):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/pwsh
$salida = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time' -Method Get
Write-Host "Time: " $salida
```

I receive this error:

```sh
pi@raspberry:~/Documents $ sudo ./a.ps1
Invoke-RestMethod : Authentication failed, see inner exception.
At /home/pi/Documents/a.ps1:2 char:11
+ $salida = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Method: GET, Re...rShell/6.1.3
}:HttpRequestMessage) [Invoke-RestMethod], HttpRequestException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
Time:  
pi@raspberry:~/Documents $
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have stumbled upon a bug with the Raspberry Pi/ARM release of Powershell. I too can replicate this issue with PowerShell's Core 6.2.3.

```
# /usr/bin/powershell -File ./mytestfile.ps1
```

Result:

```
Invoke-Webrequest : Authentication failed, see inner exception.
At mytestfile.ps1:2 char:18
+     $WebAction = Invoke-Webrequest -uri $URL -Method Default
```

But...
If I run the file from within the shell it works fine:

```
# /usr/bin/powershell
PowerShell 6.2.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/user> ./mytestfile.ps1
Downloading https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d...blah,blah,blah
Download:  OK
PS /home/user>
```

I think this needs to be reported to Microsoft to get resolved: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your answer: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33179

TL;DR : Do the below *before* launching your Powershell script from bash

export CLR_OPENSSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.1

Longer version:
The problem is not the file permissions on the script, or that of user running it. The error is coming from the Cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest`
PowerShell/.NET is dependent on the OpenSSL library version 1.0 , and Raspbian has version 1.1 installed by default. The installation instructions on Microsoft's web site just tell us to install libssl1.0, so we end up with a copy of both 1.0 and 1.1. This can confuse PowerShell under the right circumstances. Your Invoke-WebRequest is for the HTTPS communication protocol, which is HTTP encrypted using Transport Layer Security (TLS), or, formerly, its predecessor, Secure Sockets Layer (SSL). My guess is that somehow when `Invoke-WebRequest` is called within the script Powershell incorrectly tries to use version 1.1 of libssl, but when run interactivity it correctly uses libssl1.0. I am unclear as how exactly C`LR_OPENSSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.1` causes the correct behaviour, but in my experience it does work.

You can learn more about the issue by running the following script, which recursively show you the 'inner exception' of the initial exception. This gives a better view of the underpinning issue that is causing `Invoke-WebRequest` to throw the exception

```
Try {
    ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://httpbin.org/headers").Content | ConvertFrom-Json).headers
}
catch {
    $e = $_.Exception
    $msg = $e.Message
    $depth = ">"
    while ($e.InnerException) {
        $e = $e.InnerException
        $msg += "`n$depth $($e.Message)" 
        $depth += ">"
    }
    $msg
}
```

When run Interactively it worked as expected:

```
User@rpi:/home/User $ /usr/bin/powershell 
PowerShell 6.2.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/user> ./WebRequest-Test.ps1

Host        User-Agent
----        ----------
httpbin.org Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Linux 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:1…
```

But when I run it from that bash shell (without first running export `CLR_OPENSSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.1` ) I get:

```
User@rpi:/home/User $ /usr/bin/powershell WebRequest-Test.ps1 

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> Authentication failed, see inner exception.
>> The type initializer for 'SslMethods' threw an exception.
>>> The type initializer for 'Ssl' threw an exception.
>>>> The type initializer for 'SslInitializer' threw an exception.
>>>>> error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name
```